# detect selection of jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

The following code logs a value when the user types, but does not when the user selects an option from jQuery autocomplete. Is there a way to detect textbox change when the value is changed from autocomplete?

```
$('#customerid').on('input propertychange paste', function () {
    var s = $('#customerid').val().indexOf(" ");
    var n = $('#customerid').val().substr(0, s);
    console.log(n);
});
```

Comment: You need to use the events from autocomplete to get what the user selected.  http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to listen `autocompleteselect` event:

```
$('#customerid').on('input propertychange paste autocompleteselect', function () {
    var s = this.value.indexOf(" ");
    var n = this.value.substr(0, s);
    console.log(n);
});
```